# How to use In operator for comparing multiple values in EXCEL with Drools

Tags: drools

I am trying **Drools excel** to **compare some values of products** like I have P1,P2,P3...P10 Now I am comparing it with incoming value from request.

I tried in below way but I am receiving an error.

Can you please help to fix this issue. **Hope I am making a simple mistake** but not able to find it.

[image]

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 1):

You have too many parentheses.

The value in the `product` column is substituted *as is* into `$param`. The correct syntax we're looking for is `... in ("P1", "P2")`; however you've provided `("P1", "P2")` as the product value. This transforms to `in (("P1", "P2"))`, which is not correct.

Remove the parentheses from the `product` cell: `"P1", "P2"`.